# Is it possible to continue a pull request opened by someone else on Github?

Tags: git, github, pull-request

In a repository which is not mine, a third person opened a pull request. One of the owners suggested some changes to make before being able to merge it. However, the author of the pull request has not done it, and it remains open for several months without the modificqtions have been implemented.

Actually I am refering to a situation [like this one](https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio/pull/726).

I would make myslef the requested improvements.

What is the cleanest and best way to do this? Can I add my commits at the following or do I need to open a new pull request?

Comment: We can do 'git pull origin <the branch name that has the open pull request>' from our feature or local branch.  The changes from the branch will be in your branch now and we can make the modifications.  Once done we can push it to the main branch.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The only way to *update* a pull request is to push to the branch that's been PRed - so even the original repo's owner can't amend the PR, by default. It **does** make sense - for traceability's sake, at least.

So if you want to finish that work, the best thing you can do is to fork the original repo, `clone` it on your machine, add the PR's repo as a `remote`, `checkout` the PR'ed branch, `commit` on top of that, `push` those changes to your own fork, and make a new PR stating in the comments that it continues and fixes the other PR, so the original PR would get closed when yours' is merged.

In this case, something like:

```
$ # Go to https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio/ and fork it
$ git clone https://github.com/Delgan/cheerio/ && cd cheerio # assuming that's your GH username :)
$ git remote add pr-base https://github.com/digihaven/cheerio/
$ git fetch pr-base
$ git checkout pr-base/master -b 641-appendTo_prependTo
$ # work work work
$ git add #...
$ git commit -m 'Fixed all the things! See #641, fixes #726'
$ git push origin 641-appendTo_prependTo
$ # Go to your repo and make the PR
$ # ...
$ # SUCESS! (??!)
```

Comment: Forking someone else's repo isn't working for me, since I already forked the original repo, and I guess github doesn't let me fork both the original and its fork. What are my options?

Comment: Why do you need to fork it?  Why can't you just add the remote to the existing clone?

Answer (score 2):

From your branch use this command

```
git pull origin <the open pull request branch name>
```

It pulls the commits from that branch to your branch.

Make the improvements and push it to the main branch.

Comment: I thing none of this things work if you don't have write access to the original repo.